# Is there the difference in JS execution in IE6 andIE7

Tags: javascript

seems thats it is

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer, Yes.

There are subtle nuances and implementation differences.  What are the issues you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially in IE8 running in Standards Mode.

e.g.

```
//in IE6, 7, and IE8 quirks and IE8 compatibility mode, this will return
//the first element with either a 'name' or 'id' attribute value of "description"
//(CasE iNsenSiTIVE)

//in IE8 standards mode, it will return the first element with the
//EXACT id attribute value of "description"
var desc = document.getElementById('description');
```

plus dozens of changes with .setAttribute() and .getAttribute()

Comment: why IE8 standart is so important

Comment: @unknown (google) - was that a question? or a statement?  If a question I'd be happy to list all the IE8 standards mode differences.